# Is "less than once a week" incorrect?

Tags: grammaticality

Someone told me that once a week is the least so there won't be such a thing like "less than once a week" but twice or once a month is less than "once a week" am I wrong?

Is this usage incorrect?

Comment: It's fine.  I don't ride my bike often at the moment.  Certainly less than once a week.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it.  You could attempt to be more specific with "once or twice a month" or some such, but it all depends on how precise you need to be, as well as how much you even can say with certainty about the frequency.

Comment: Very strictly speaking, "less than once a week" is "zero times a week" i.e. *never* - so the correct way would be to say "less often than once a week". But I don't think anyone is so pedant.

Comment: You are right, and the someone is wrong. (But this is more a question about time or logic than it is a question about English.)

Comment: @michael.hor257k - I would say that you are flat-out wrong on that.

Comment: The question isn't clear.  Are you saying that once a week is the shortest time period that can be expressed, or once a week is the least frequent something is allowed to occur?  If the latter, "once a week at least" means twice a week is OK but once a month is not.  Your last sentence would be a refutation of the first interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

"Less than once a week" is fine. This could mean 0.75 times per week, or 0.1 times per week, or any other number less than one time per week. Technically "never" is logically consistent with "less than once time per week", although this would be misleading.

[Google ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=less+than+once+a+day%2C+less+than+once+a+week%2Cless+than+once+a+month%2Cless+than+once+a+year&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cless%20than%20once%20a%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cless%20than%20once%20a%20week%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cless%20than%20once%20a%20month%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cless%20than%20once%20a%20year%3B%2Cc0) shows "less than once a week" to be nearly as popular as "less than once a month", and much more popular than "less than once a day" or "less than once a year" are.

Comment: Correct.  "Less than once a week" is describing a *rate* (events per unit time), and, except in fairly constrained circumstances, rates can be fractional.  There is nothing syntactically or semantically wrong with the usage, and it *is* idiomatic.

Comment: As you say, "less than once a week" applies quite well to averages of occurrences spread over several or many weeks that come out in the range of fractions between 0 per week and 1 per week. In contrast, "fewer than one a week" would imply (to some readers and hearers, anyway) a whole number less than one per week, which would amount to saying "zero a week" or "never."